# How do I make data orderly on the message box? python-tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, messagebox

My current goal is to display data onto a 
[message box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gL2GI.jpg).
As this picture shows, the data is all over the place, but if I send it to [Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LhQvG.jpg) it looks perfectly fine whereas the message box is just not even.

How can I even out the displayed data on messagebox just to look like the excel?

**Here is my code:**

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.messagebox as tm
import pandas
import datetime


def currency_rate():
    dfs=pandas.read_html('https://rate.bot.com.tw/xrt?Lang=en-US')
    currency=dfs[1] 
    currency= currency.iloc[:,0:5] 
    currency.columns=['currency','cash-buying','cash-selling','spot-buying','spot-selliing'] 
    currency['currency'] =currency['currency'].str.extract('\((\w+)\)')  
    date=datetime.datetime.now() 
    result_date="Update: Date {:4}.{:02}.{:02}-Time {:02}:{:02}:{:02}".format(date.year,date.month,date.day,date.hour,date.minute,date.second)
    tm.showinfo(title =str(result_date), message =str(currency))  

def currency_rate_import():    
    dfs=pandas.read_html('https://rate.bot.com.tw/xrt?Lang=en-US')
    currency=dfs[1] 
    currency= currency.iloc[:,0:5] 
    currency.columns=['currency','cash-buying','cash\nselling','spot\nbuying','spot-selliing'] 
    currency['currency'] =currency['currency'].str.extract('\((\w+)\)')  
    date=datetime.datetime.now() 
    currency.to_excel('Currency Rate{:4}{:02}{:02}-Daily.xlsx'.format(date.year,date.month,date.day))

my_window=tk.Tk()


btn2=tk.Button(my_window,text="Export (Excel)",font="Calibri 14",width=25,height=1,command=currency_rate_import)
btn2.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM) 
btn1=tk.Button(my_window,text="Today\'s exchange rate",font="Calibri 14",background="yellow",width=25,height=1,command=currency_rate)
btn1.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM) 

my_window.mainloop()
```

Comment: If you're counting on string length to form "columns," you'll need to use a fixed-width font as well - Calibri is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have good experience using pandas with [tabulate](https://github.com/astanin/python-tabulate) and then inserting in Tkinter window with [tkinterhtml](https://bitbucket.org/aivarannamaa/tkinterhtml).

You have "stralign" and "numalign" in tabulate and even "floatfmt" for all sorts of formats and alignment while creating tables.

example for usage:

```
from tabulate import tabulate
from tkinterhtml import HtmlFrame

html = tabulate(df, 
                headers='keys',
                floatfmt=",.1f", tablefmt='html',
                numalign='center', stralign='center')
top = tk.Toplevel()
hf = HtmlFrame(top)
hf.pack()
hf.set_content(html)
```