# Print on Label tkinter

Tags: python, postgresql, tkinter, label, psycopg2

Making a connection with PostgreSQL DB, I want to show into a label a hand-made table, making a SELECT on my DB. It's all right about the database connection and query. But something went wrong. I'm putting just below the source code and screenshot of what the program showed.

```
from tkinter import *
import psycopg2 # LIBRARY FOR CONNECT TO THE POSTGRESQL DB

root = Tk()
menubar = Menu(root)

file = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
file.add_command(label="Exit", command=root.quit)
menubar.add_cascade(label="Principal", menu=file)

con = psycopg2.connect(  # CONNECT TO THE POSTGRESQL DB
    host="localhost",
    database="escola",
    user="postgres",
    password=248657
)

v = StringVar()

cur = con.cursor()  # CURSOR
cur.execute("SELECT id, nome, dt_nasc, nome_mae, nome_pai FROM alunos")  # EXECUTE QUERY

rows = cur.fetchall()

v.set('+----+-----------------------------+--------------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+')
v.set('|ID'.ljust(5) + '| Nome'.ljust(30) + '| Data de Nascimento |'.ljust(21) + ' Nome da     Mãe'.ljust(29) + '| Nome do Pai'.ljust(30) + '|')
v.set('+----+-----------------------------+--------------------+-----------------------------+------    -----------------------+')
for r in rows:
    v.set(f'|{r[0]}'.ljust(5) + f'|  {r[1]}'.ljust(30) + f'|  {r[2]}'.ljust(21) + f'|      {r[3]}'.ljust(30) + f'|  {r[4]}'.ljust(30) + '|')
v.set('+----+-----------------------------+--------------------+-----------------------------+------    -----------------------+')

cur.close()  # CLOSE CURSOR


box = Label(root, textvariable=v).pack() # THE LABEL

root.config(menu=menubar) # SETTING THE MENU
root.mainloop()
```

**ScreeShot:**

[image]

Comment: No mater whats going on you set `v` to `+----+-----`... at the end. So the result will always be the same.

Comment: I think you are trying to append values to `v`, but what you're really doing is over-writing `v` every time you call `v.set()`

Comment: Read about [`ttk.Treeview`](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/tree.html) and [tkinterhtml](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58289427/7414759)

Comment: A label is the wrong choice for multiline data. Have you considered using a `Text` widget which is specifically designed for multline text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is going on here is you are overwriting v with each line. Instead consider writing a multi line string then setting that final value to `v`.

That said there are a few other options you might want to try. For example you could use a text box and then just `insert()` at the end new lines and that would work. Or better yet when working with data-sets you probably want to use a Treeview to organize your data.

Try this and let me know if you have any questions:

Replace this:

```
v.set('+----+-----------------------------+--------------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+')
v.set('|ID'.ljust(5) + '| Nome'.ljust(30) + '| Data de Nascimento |'.ljust(21) + ' Nome da     Mãe'.ljust(29) + '| Nome do Pai'.ljust(30) + '|')
v.set('+----+-----------------------------+--------------------+-----------------------------+------    -----------------------+')
for r in rows:
    v.set(f'|{r[0]}'.ljust(5) + f'|  {r[1]}'.ljust(30) + f'|  {r[2]}'.ljust(21) + f'|      {r[3]}'.ljust(30) + f'|  {r[4]}'.ljust(30) + '|')
v.set('+----+-----------------------------+--------------------+-----------------------------+------    -----------------------+')
```

With this:

```
separator = '+----+-----------------------------+--------------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+'
prep_string = ''''''

prep_string = '{}{}\n'.format(prep_string, separator)
prep_string = '{}{}\n'.format('|ID'.ljust(5) + '| Nome'.ljust(30) + '| Data de Nascimento |'.ljust(21) + ' Nome da     Mãe'.ljust(29) + '| Nome do Pai'.ljust(30) + '|')
prep_string = '{}{}\n'.format(prep_string, separator)
for r in rows:
    prep_string = '{}{}\n'.format(f'|{r[0]}'.ljust(5) + f'|  {r[1]}'.ljust(30) + f'|  {r[2]}'.ljust(21) + f'|      {r[3]}'.ljust(30) + f'|  {r[4]}'.ljust(30) + '|')
prep_string = '{}{}\n'.format(prep_string, separator)

v.set(prep_string)
```

If we print the value of `prep_string` we a full set of everything you tried to add at once. Note below I just quoted your variables into one string to show how it would work. Your values should represent whatever data you have.

```
+----+-----------------------------+--------------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+
|ID'.ljust(5) + '| Nome'.ljust(30) + '| Data de Nascimento |'.ljust(21) + ' Nome da     Mãe'.ljust(29) + '| Nome do Pai'.ljust(30) + '|
+----+-----------------------------+--------------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+
|ID'.ljust(5) + '| Nome'.ljust(30) + '| Data de Nascimento |'.ljust(21) + ' Nome da     Mãe'.ljust(29) + '| Nome do Pai'.ljust(30) + '|
|ID'.ljust(5) + '| Nome'.ljust(30) + '| Data de Nascimento |'.ljust(21) + ' Nome da     Mãe'.ljust(29) + '| Nome do Pai'.ljust(30) + '|
|ID'.ljust(5) + '| Nome'.ljust(30) + '| Data de Nascimento |'.ljust(21) + ' Nome da     Mãe'.ljust(29) + '| Nome do Pai'.ljust(30) + '|
+----+-----------------------------+--------------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+
```

For a text widget version try something like this:

```
import tkinter as tk

separator = '+----+-----------------------------+--------------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+'

root = tk.Tk()
text = tk.Text(root, wrap='none', font='TkFixedFont', width=130)
text.pack()

text.insert('end', separator + '\n')
text.insert('end', '''|ID'.ljust(5) + '| Nome'.ljust(30) + '| Data de Nascimento |'.ljust(21) + ' Nome da     Mãe'.ljust(29) + '| Nome do Pai'.ljust(30) + '|''' + '\n')
text.insert('end', separator + '\n')
for r in range(3):
    text.insert('end', '''|ID'.ljust(5) + '| Nome'.ljust(30) + '| Data de Nascimento |'.ljust(21) + ' Nome da     Mãe'.ljust(29) + '| Nome do Pai'.ljust(30) + '|''' + '\n')
text.insert('end', separator + '\n')

root.mainloop()
```

Results:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. About your third "prep_string" instance, the interpreter (PyCharm) accused that is not declared. I didn't understand this information.

Comment: @LucasRibeiro that is odd. I am using PyCharm and is not saying anything like that for me. By 3rd are you talking about `prep_string = '''{}{}\n'''.format('|ID'.ljust(5)`... If so maybe its saying that one of your variables is not declared.

Comment: I made some adjustments to the text display. I don't know if it was my adaptations that still have the same problems. Here is the screenshots below:

First: https://i.imgur.com/8VAbXl5.png
Second: https://i.imgur.com/DO9977Y.png

Comment: First: i.imgur.com/8VAbXl5.png 
Second: i.imgur.com/DO9977Y.png

Comment: @LucasRibeiro well you are not combining the strings like in my example. You are creating a single line. Why did you remove `format()` from the example. It was there for a reason. `'{}{}\n'.format()` is doing 2 things here. First it is adding the next line to the quoted string. 2nd we add `\n` to tell it that the line is add and we need to move to new line. By removing this from the example your not going to get a multi line label.

Comment: Oh, I think I solved it. Some lines were missing the "prep_string" before the text for print it on.

The result is it: https://i.imgur.com/FpokKuW.png

But on the terminal, the results appears aligned: https://i.imgur.com/91mEmos.png

Do some identifications like ".ljust(10)" or "{20:}" do not works in Labels?

Comment: @LucasRibeiro You need to set the font of the label to a mono-spaced font. The console is mono-spaced but the label is not by default. Try adding `font='TkFixedFont' to the label.

Comment: Done! https://i.imgur.com/Q9CB4av.png
Thank you for your support @Mike - SMT !